# Can an SSD have a MBR and a bootloader?

Tags: linux, ssd, bootloader, mbr

I installed both Linux and Windows on my newly bought SSD (`sda`). When I installed Linux, I chose to install the bootloader on the SSD (`sda`).

After I finished, I got only a black screen when I chose to boot from SSD, but the strangest thing was that I got a GRUB menu when I chose to boot from the HDD (`sdb`).

I'm sure I chose the SSD as the location for the bootloader to be installed. So why did the bootloader transfer from the SSD to the HDD?

Does it mean that an SSD can't hold an MBR or bootloader at the very beginning of it?

Comment: I think you just made an error when type `grub-install /dev/sdX`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em no, i'm sure i didn't make that wrong, because i have tried to reinstall linux as well as the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter if it's an SSD or and HDD. Try physically removing the HDD before installing Windows and Linux, so the installer doesn't touch the HDD. It also might be better if you install windows first, then Linux.

Something similar happened with me, where I chose a specific partition, but other partitions were modified too.

If you can't physically remove the HDD, you can clone it to somewhere else, as a method of backup.

Answer (score -1):

Some distros tend to wipe anything on the primary drive reported in the BIOS. The most failsafe is to disconnect any other drives, except the drive you're installing Linux on.

I once wiped the TrueCrypt bootloader on my Win7-drive, when all I really wanted was to install OpenSUSE on an external drive. Luckily I had a CD with a backup of the bootloader.